# UNITY | Call method of unknown class

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have `Health.cs` on all my `enemy` objects.

When `enemy` get damage i want to alert this in different classes. (Depends on `enemy` type)

So in `Health.cs` i added `public UnityEngine.Object alertInScript;`

I change `alertInScript` via Unity Editor. I put there class which i want to alert.

Each `alertInScript` class have same method `DamageAlert`

But i can't call it, because c# can't see this `alertInScript` class before game starts.

So i always getting error.

Im noobo in c# and unity, please tell me if it's even possible.

Or how i can get same result using something else?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Referencing EnemyBear.cs (source code file) is a not a valid thing to do. Don't do that ever, because they're meant only to exist as a source (code) assets while in Editor. What you need to do is to reference specific Components instead or write your code so those components will be found by some specific GetComponent pattern

---

Interface is the way to go here:

```
public interface IHealthAlert
{
    void Alert ( Health health );
}
```

Implement interface like this:

```
public class AlertedComponent : MonoBehaviour, IHealthAlert
{
    void IHealthAlert.Alert ( Health health)
    {
        Debug.Log( "alerted!" , gameObject );
    }
}
```

And add this `AlertedComponent` next to `Health` (exactly the same GameObject)

Then in Health.cs call it like this:

```
var components = GetComponents<IHealthAlert>();
foreach( var comp in components )
{
    comp.Alert( this );
}
```

Comment: **Note** that you can replace `GetComponents` with [GetComponentsInChildren](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInChildren.html) or [GetComponentsInParent](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Component.GetComponentsInParent.html)